# Get Td innert html without input tags - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html like below:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>LG G5
        <input data-productid="da15d739" value="da15d739" name="PurchaseDetails[0].StoreDetails[2].ProductId" type="hidden">
        <input name="PurchaseDetails[0].StoreDetails.Index" value="146" type="hidden">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to  get just `LG G5` in the `Td`.

how can Get that with Jquery ?

Comment: `$(TD_SELECTOR).text()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use .text()

`$("td").text()` will return the text without html tags

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the text node only:

```
 $('td').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE; 
 }).text();
```

Comment: This returns the text node element. To get the text you can append `.text()` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v3yy04cw/).

Please find the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>LG G5
        <input data-productid="da15d739" value="da15d739" name="PurchaseDetails[0].StoreDetails[2].ProductId" type="hidden">
        <input name="PurchaseDetails[0].StoreDetails.Index" value="146" type="hidden">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  var data = $.trim($('td').text());
  console.log('sha', data);
});
```